# Getting geometry with coordinates in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, geometry

I have a latitude coordinate and longitude coordinate. I have a table with geometries.

What function must I execute to use the coordinates to get a geometry containing the point made by these coordinates?

Comment: Where have you looked to try and answer your question before asking it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ST_INTERSECTS`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html)

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE ST_Intersects(
        geom,
        ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-71.064544 42.28787)',4326)
       );
```

Comment: If you change `ST_GeographyFromText` to `ST_GeomFromText`, I can accept your answer

Comment: @Username yeah, that is one of those great functions that works with either geographies or geometries